# MySQL process takes up to 180% of the CPU (optimisation need)

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization, configuration, mysqltuner

- I have a dedicated server with 128 GB of RAM and an 8 core CPU and
  2TB hard drive.
- I have **cPanel** and **MySQL** installed in the same server.
- In this server I have 12 websites hosted including 5 with a large
  traffic, these 5 sites have **60000 visits per day** in total.
- Sites in Wordpress and Drupal and Prestashop
- The database sizes of these sites between **200 MB and 1.5 GB each**.

I have a MYSQL config on **/etc/my.cnf**:

```
[mysqld]
performance-schema             =ON
bind-address                   =127.0.0.1
max_allowed_packet             =256M
#
local-infile                   =0
default-storage-engine         =MyISAM

open_files_limit               =10000
key_buffer_size                =8G
table_open_cache               =6000
max_heap_table_size            =256M
tmp_table_size                 =256M
sort_buffer_size               =1M
read_buffer_size               =1M
read_rnd_buffer_size           =2M
join_buffer_size               =128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size        =64M
thread_cache_size              =200
query_cache_size               =0
query_cache_type               =0
query_cache_limit              =256M
wait_timeout                   =300
max_connections                =500
max_user_connections           =30
log-error                      ="/var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log"

innodb_file_per_table          =1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        =8G
innodb_log_buffer_size         =64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit =2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout       =50
innodb_flush_method            =O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size           =1G


explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
secure-file-priv = "/home/secure-file-priv"

# Log slow queries taking more than 10 seconds to complete
# use mysqldumpslow to analyze
slow-query-log                 =1
slow-query-log-file = /var/lib/mysql/myslow.log

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet             =128M
```

> **MySQLTuner** is a script written in Perl that allows you to review a MySQL installation quickly and make adjustments to increase performance and stability. The current configuration variables and status data is retrieved and presented in a brief format along with some basic performance suggestions.

And I have execute MySQLTuner script to optimize my MySQL configuration :

```
./mysqltuner.pl
```

And tnis is the Output:

```
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log file
Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log file
MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: [https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/11/16/table_cache-negative-scalability/][1]
Beware that open_files_limit (65536) variable
should be greater than table_open_cache (5000)
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
Variables to adjust:
join_buffer_size (> 64.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
table_open_cache (> 5000)
```

I have adjust these two value and restarted MySQL, now recommendations is:

```
-------- Recommendations --------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log file
Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log file
MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
```

---

The problem is the server has a **High Load Average between 4 and 12**
Load Averages: 5.40 6.62 7.40
Load Averages: 4.84 8.34 7.61
Load Averages: 12.05 12.48 10.74

And the **MySQL process** takes up to **180% of the CPU**

```
Pid Owner   Priority    CPU %   Memory %    Command
3618 (Trace) (Kill) mysql   0     180.13      5.92  /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log --open-files-limit=10000 --pid-file=server.domain.com.pid
```

- **Which configuration do you suggest?**
- **Is it necessary to separate the database to another server?**
- **Are there any other recommendations?**

---

A new test done with mysqltuner.pl, here is the result:

```
 ./mysqltuner.pl
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.4 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.6.38-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log(274K)
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log exists
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log contains 75 warning(s).
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log contains 97 error(s).
[--] 43 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log
[--] 1) 2018-01-18 09:00:29 19228 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2018-01-16 14:07:40 29765 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2018-01-16 14:06:04 28249 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2018-01-16 11:51:00 5274 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2018-01-16 09:05:09 13555 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2018-01-16 08:11:26 3618 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 2018-01-15 21:13:52 22775 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 2018-01-15 17:23:46 26000 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 9) 2018-01-15 17:22:56 25298 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 10) 2018-01-15 15:30:28 9766 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 48 shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log
[--] 1) 2018-01-18 09:00:27 29765 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2018-01-16 14:07:37 28249 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2018-01-16 14:06:01 5274 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 2018-01-16 11:50:58 13555 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 2018-01-16 09:04:33 12957 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 2018-01-16 09:04:17 12439 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 2018-01-16 09:04:02 11933 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 8) 2018-01-16 09:03:48 11366 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 9) 2018-01-16 09:03:47 3618 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 10) 2018-01-16 08:11:23 22775 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 271M (Tables: 227)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 2G (Tables: 1560)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 7d 6h 52m 34s (518M q [823.132 qps], 2M conn, TX: 1723G, RX: 114G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 94% / 6%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 125.7G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 81.4G
[--] Other process memory: 2.1G
[--] Total buffers: 16.3G global + 132.2M per thread (500 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 543M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 24.0G (19.06% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 81.4G (64.80% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (696/518M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 11% (55/500)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.02%  (494/2524679)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (135K temp sorts / 78M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 77629
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 31% (11M on disk / 36M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (55 created / 2M connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (4K open / 711K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (729/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (764M immediate / 764M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 543.3M
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.3% (1B used / 8B cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0G/38.6M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (3B cached / 2K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 0.0% (1B cached / 43K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 8.0G/2.8G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 1.0G * 2/8.0G should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (163467971977 hits/ 163468105140 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 44.89% (19521578 hits/ 43484887 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 23963309 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/mysqlerror.log file
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/11/16/table_cache-negative-scalability/
    Beware that open_files_limit (65536) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (6000)
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
Variables to adjust:
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    table_open_cache (> 6000)
```

Comment: We need complete report from MySQLTuner posted, please.

Please confirm or correct you have 2 GB hard drive by editing your question.
If your hard drive is 2 GB, they why would you need key_buffer_size 8G and innodb_buffer_pool_size 8G?

Comment: Sorry, I have corred this information, I have 2 TB not SSD it is a simple Hard Disk
Serveur HOST-128L - Xeon D-1520 - 128GB - SoftRaid 2x2To

Comment: Wondering what your MySQL situation is at this time?  If any suggestions were helpful, please consider upvote or accept for answers that improved your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

things to do in your my.cnf,

thread_cache_size=100  #from 200 to prevent Out Of Memory  V8 suggests 100 CAP for durability/predictability.

After we can see your complete MySQLTuner report (minimum uptime of 24 hours, please) additional suggestions will be possible.

Is your hard drive SSD or rotating hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Chewing up the CPU?  Have the slowlog turned on?  Lower `long_query_time` to only 1 (second).  Wait a day, then summarize the slowlog with `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest`, then work on the slowest couple of queries.

Since I see WordPress, I recommend following the tips here to speed up most uses of `wp_postmeta`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

What is a "visit"?  The number of queries would be more useful in this discussion.

I see that the default Engine is MyISAM.  But are they actually such?  If so, consider switching to InnoDB for better concurrency.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

2GB hard drive?  Maybe a decade ago.

What version of MySQL are you using?

The settings you showed should have used only a fraction of your huge 128GB of RAM.  Something is missing.

mysqltuner's recommendations are often not-quite-right.  You chopped off the interesting part of the output.

Comment: My server:
Intel  Xeon-D 1540
8c/16t - 2.1GHz /2.6GHz
128GB DDR4 ECC 2133 MHz
SoftRAID  2x2TB 
250 Mbps bandwidth
vRack: 10 Mbps
[server specification](https://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/hosting/1801host06.xml)
-----
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.38, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: @tmedtcom - That's the version of the commandline tool.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ver%';`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for complete MySQLTuner report.

More things to do in your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
key_buffer_size=2G #from 8G for 1G used X ~2
max_connections=100 # from 200 for V8 REFMAN 100 CAP
#sort_buffer_size=1M  disabled to use 2M default
#read_buffer_size=1M  disabled to use 128K default
read_rnd_buffer_size=64K # from 2M to reduce RD load
#join_buffer_size=128M  disabled to use 128K default
delay_key_writes=OFF  # from default of ON, get it DONE
expire_logs_days=5  # will cover weekends for you
key_cache_age_threshold=64800  # to avoid reading ISAM idx for 18 hours
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=ON  #prepare to minimize startup
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=ON  # last used rows will be in RAM
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=ON  # need to be proactive in eliminating DL
innodb_stats_sample_pages=32  # from 8 for more accurate cardinality
max_allowed_packet=1M  # if > needed after START ..SET @max_allowed_packet=nnnnnnnnnn  up to 1G
max_seeks_for_key=32  # from huge number to something reasonable
max_write_lock_count=2  # then give RD a chance
slow_query_log=ON  # from default of OFF, need to know every day, correct w idx usually
query_prealloc_size=32K  # from 8192 to support parsing all day
```

There are more opportunities.  After applying NO MORE than one per day so you  know what really makes a difference, replace postings (GStatus, Gv, MySQLTuner, my.cnf etc for further analysis.